# Product attribute filter code

Tags: magento2, filter

How does product attribute filtering works? It seems to return values through ajax when some URL like this is called "test.html?color=5459&size=5447" but where is this ajax is being called? And what controller method it's calling? I need to analyze its code and can't seem to locate them.